# Creating new local repository for a project in VS Code and getting all the files of parent repository as untracked

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-untracked

I usually create my repositories in a folder (let's call it "Repo-Folder") I created inside Documents.

I probably did something wrong with the terminal while trying to learn about GIT branches and merges.

Since that moment everytime i create a new repo for a project inside "Repo-Folder" I get all the files in Documents as Untracked.

What should I do? I don't want  to remove the untracked files as I'm afraid it's gonna delete everything in documents.

And even if that will not delete everything in Documents, how can I avoid getting this again and again?[getting everything i have in documents and adding it to the project repo as untracked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnPPs.jpg)

P.S. This only happen if I create a repo in Documents, not on Desktop for example.

I don't really wannt to touch anything as I'm scared I'm going to do some permanent damange to my mac.

Comment: you have a `~/Documents/.git` folder, delete it

Comment: You are right, I can't seethe git file in Documents, but if I try to enter it with the terminal I can, so that means it exists. I'm a noob with Terminal and Git honestly, what's the command to delete the .git file exactly? And why is it "invisible" in Documents? TY so much

Comment: if you want to delete it rename it on the terminal, then you can see it in the Windows Explorer